# Adding a custom Gradle plugin to a project

Tags: gradle

I'm attempting to add a custom Gradle plugin that I've created (I built a jar with Gradle called gradle-todo.jar) in a separate project.  However, when I run the external project's build, I get an error like the following:

> Could not find implementation class 'x.y.z.ToDo' for plugin 'ToDo'
>   specified in
>   jar:file:......./gradle-todo/build/libs/gradle-todo.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/ToDo.properties.

ToDo.properties specifies that the implementation class is x.y.z.ToDo.  The class is located in the JAR in the expected location (eg. x.y.z in the above example).  My build script looks like this:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
      classpath files('../gradle-todo/build/libs/gradle-todo.jar')
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'ToDo'
```

Any idea as to what's going on?  Most of the posts I've read about including plugins are geared toward pulling them in from some sort of non-flat repository, but I'd like to just include the JAR from the file system for testing purposes.

Comment: That error makes it look like it's finding the jar and looking up the implementation class fine. If you think the implementation class is in that same jar, I'd double check. Everything there seems fine to me. What's the full stack trace of the error and the contents of the jar?

Comment: Most likely, the plugin class referenced in `ToDo.properties` doesn't exist in the Jar. Perhaps you got the class name wrong (e.g. didn't fully qualify it).

Comment: Turns out I was, in fact, missing a qualifier in the full class name (right in the middle of the string, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a qualifier in the full class name.  It appears to be loading the Jar correctly now.

Answer (score -1):

This error is also occurred when package declaration is missing in class file.

If `package com.mydomain` is missing at the top of your class file, you will get this error.